# htaccess show the same content of main domain, when you are on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have website `www.domain.com` (on server root is in `/domain.com/web/`), now I created subdomain `m.domain.com` (on server root is in `/domain.com/sub/m/`).

I added .htaccess to subdomain root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?m\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../../web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it is showing `Internal Server Error`.

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But that will redirect you to the main domain. I need to stay on subdomain, but have the same content as on main domain.

Also I have checked more solutions here on SO, but none of them is working.

**EDIT:**

I tried in Apache to set up another VirtualHost:

```
DocumentRoot /domain.com/web
<Directory "/domain.com/web">
allow from all
Options None
</Directory>
ServerName m.domain.com
ServerAlias m.domain.com
```

Now also main domain and also subdomain shows 503 - Forbidden.

Comment: You checked into your apache's error logs?

Comment: Usually, errors are shown in `error.log` not `access.log`. Your `access.log` entry confirms, that there is an "Internal Server Error" (`500`).

Comment: If you want the same content on both domains, why do you have separate `DocumentRoot`s? You could set both roots to `/domain.com/web/`.

Comment: error_log was disabled. now there is showing too many redirects, so it is cycled infinitive - `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

Comment: Search for redirect loop and environment variable `REDIRECT_STATUS`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13008782/1741542

Comment: @OlafDietsche I want to use same source code for main www.domain.com and also m.domain.com, but of course for m.domain.com there will be used some different layout; but all other will be the same. I also tried to set VirtualHost in Apache, but didnt worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this has to be overly complicated. If you want to use the same content then I can see a few ways to do this.

1. Just added `m.domain.com` to the [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive in the Apache VirtualHost config and all requests for that sub domain will display the content in the document root that is set but keep the subdomain displayed. **(Most Recommended)**
2. Set the `document root` of your subdomain config file the same as your main domain name. **(Less Recommended)**
3. Use `mod_proxy` via the `P` flag to reverse proxy the content so that the sub domain is still displayed. **(Least Recommended)**

example using `mod_proxy` via `P` flag.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [P]
```

Side Note: `m.domain.com` must be defined in DNS pointing to your server IP as well.

Your VirtualHost for your main domain should look something like this. You don't need a vhost for your `m` subdomain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias m.example.com 
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain.com/web"
    <Directory "/www/domain.com/web">
       # deny .htaccess use.
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache for all config changes.

Comment: `*.domain.com` is defined in DNS and pointing to the same server IP. But I would like to use your 1st solution, but dont know, how.

Comment: @Legionar click on the link to ServerAlias. It explains how it works.

Comment: What version of apache are you using?

Comment: Apache version 2.2.16

Comment: Apache failed to start - `Illegal override option #` on line `AllowOverride None # deny .htaccess use.` When I removed it, then it works, but not correct, because it redirect from subdomain to main domain, so the URL is changed, but that I dont want to.

Comment: I fixed the line. Did you remove any of your redirects? Also Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Thank you much! I also needed to add there back `ServerAlias domain.com`, to work also without `www` to access main domain.